# count all occurrences of string in a text file using grep, but with multiple search string

Tags: regex, string, bash, unix

I am using the below code to search using grep. If I am using only 1 search string, it works, but if with multiple search string, which is what I'm doing, it wont

Using 1 search pattern

```
grep -o <search string> * | wc -l
```

Using multiple search pattern

```
grep -o '<search string>\|<search string>\|<search string>\|' *| wc -l
```

Is there something that I missed?

Comment: What error do you get? it works to me.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work ?

Comment: the return number is different, using 1 search patter, it returns 55, using 2 or more search pattern, it returns 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a trailing | symbol in your search string.

Try changing:

```
grep -o '<search string>\|<search string>\|<search string>\|' *| wc -l
```

to

```
grep -o '<search string>\|<search string>\|<search string>\' *| wc -l
```

Comment: HA! I'm sorry about that, my bad... I'll check this out :)

Answer (score 0):

- Your regex seems to be wrong as it is ending with a pipe i.e. `|`
- You don't need `wc -l` as you can use `grep -c` also

You can use:

```
grep -co 'string1\|string2\|string3' *
```

Comment: No. `-co` together does not provide the correct result. For example `grep -co hello <<< "hello hello"` returns `1` (at least to me).

Comment: `wc -l` will only give count of files where these patterns are found

Comment: I already tried that, it returns 16, where it should 55. I think its because the text file I'm using is all in 1 line. But if the text file is arrange correctly with newline, grep -co works

Comment: Again no (I am sorry :D). `wc -l` will count the lines of the previous output. `grep -o hello <<< "hello hello" | wc -l` will return `2`, for example.

Comment: Also you need to see that `herestring` will behave differently than using `*` (all files).

Comment: nope, it return a different number, 16 to be exact. the correct number is 55

Comment: But how can anyone test it without enough information in your question.